# How would I extract only specific text from this webpage?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for ways to take this line of code:

```
{"id":"76561198170104957","names":[{"name":"Mountain Dew"},{"name":"Sugardust"}],"kills":2394,"deaths":2617,"ff_kills":89,"ff_deaths":110,"playtime":"P5DT3H45M18S"}
```

and extract ONLY the "kills, deaths, ff_kills, and ff_deaths strings and their associated numbers into a list. This code varies in length depending on the user, so a static index won't really work I don't think. The code is also read from a webpage if that opens up any possibilities. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That format is called JSON. You can easily parse it with python. Example:

```
import json
line = r'{"id":"76561198170104957","names":[{"name":"Mountain Dew"},{"name":"Sugardust"}],"kills":2394,"deaths":2617,"ff_kills":89,"ff_deaths":110,"playtime":"P5DT3H45M18S"}'
j = json.loads(line)
print(j['kills']);
```